# Inner function supposed to execute as a method returns undefined

Tags: javascript, closures

Could anyone explain why I get the error shown below? Thanks

Source:
"Javascript Closures" by Richard Cornford http://www.jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/#clObjI

Full version at [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eCTJF3g6Mg6o2ABA7cfq?p=preview)

```
function associateObjWithEvent(obj, methodName){
  return (function(e){
    e = e||window.event;
    console.log(typeof obj[methodName]); // undefined
```

here I get **TypeError: obj[methodName] is not a function**

```
    return obj[methodName](e, this);
  });
};

function DhtmlObject(elementId){
  var el = document.getElementById(elementId);
  if(el){
    el.onclick = associateObjWithEvent(this, "doOnClick");
    el.onmouseover = associateObjWithEvent(this, "doMouseOver");
    el.onmouseout = associateObjWithEvent(this, "doMouseOut");
  }
};

DhtmlObject.prototype.doOnClick = function(event, element){
    console.log('OnClick');
};
DhtmlObject.prototype.doMouseOver = function(event, element){
    console.log('MouseOver');
};
DhtmlObject.prototype.doMouseOut = function(event, element){
    console.log('MouseOut');
};

var test = DhtmlObject("test");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that the object `this` does not refer to what you think it does. It refers to the global object, i.e. window, and window does not have these methods.

You should create the object DhtmlObject with the `new` keyword in your last line. That will make `this` bind to your new object.

Comment: Perfect now! Thank you very much!